# How would you write a statement that is JavaScript imbedded in HTML vs normal JavaScript that would be written into a file?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, onclick

How would you write the statement bellow, that is JavaScript imbedded in HTML into normal JavaScript that would be written into a file? I am making a toggle switch, and I want to have the toggle after being clicked and going through the transformation go to a new file page. To make this possible I need to know the non-imbedded version of the function. This is what it is:

```
<div class="statement">Slide to Play!</div>
<div class="container">
<div class="play" onclick= "this.classId.toggle('active')"> 
<div class="inner-square"></div>
</div></div>
```

And in JavaScript this is what I have that doesn't work:

```
const transition = document.querySelector('play');
Promise.all(
    document.getElementById("play").onclick = function() {
        transition.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
            console.log('Transition ended');
            location.assign("gamepage.html")
    }
);

Promise.all(
    
    })
).then(transition.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
    console.log('Transition ended');location.assign("gamepage.html")});
```

Comment: Why the `Promise.all`? That doesn't make any sense

Comment: When the script was embedded, was it in the <head> or before the closing </body>? Wondering if the DOM is not ready when running from <script>

Comment: The script was embedded in the </body>

Answer (score -1):

Is it possible that the javascript is running before the DOM has loaded? Per the guidelines here [$(document).ready equivalent without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery)

Wrap your javascript with the following:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  //do work
});
```

This should ensure that the whole HTML of the page has been loaded before your javascript is executed. If it was working while embedded, it may have been since you mentioned that your javascript was previously placed before the closing  tag - the whole page was loaded by then.

Comment: I think i might have mistyped my question, I just want the part embedded in JavaScript to be

Comment: for the onclick= "this.classId.toggle('active')" part